# Windows 10 Pro Infused Apps

Tags: windows-10

C:\Windows\InfusedApps\Applications is where all of the infused apps are located. 3d Builder, AppConnectior, Bing apps, Office, Solitare, store, Xbox, etc. 
I don't want to have to uninstall each one of these apps for each individual AD User that decides to log onto this PC. Would it be feasible to rename this folder, lock it down so only administrators can access this folder, or remove it so that none of the applications will install with each individual user? As typical in AD, we don't allow individual users to uninstall or install applications as that is locked down. We also don't want them to be playing solitaire, or using the XBOX app,  Issue with virus & spyware getting on the PC's in the past, and other unwanted apps. What would it do to the OS? Would it give issues? I stopped the XBOX services and it caused me to have to rebuild the machine for the third time.

Answer (score 5):

If you are in a Enterprise and want to roll out Windows 10, look for the `Windows 10 Enterprise LTSB Edition`. This edition is available for Volume License users and [comes without any of the preinstalled apps](http://winaero.com/blog/there-is-a-windows-10-edition-without-universal-apps-pre-installed/).

You have a clean start:

[image]

and don't need to remove any apps.